# MySQL Inner Join Limit Result From Second Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following data in my table.

```
Table Books
Id | Book_Name
1  | Java Programming
2  | PHP Programming
3  | HTML5

Table Chapters
Book Id | Chapter_Number
1       | Chapter 1
1       | Chapter 1v2
1       | Chapter 1v3
2       | Chapter 2 Release 1
2       | Chapter 2 Rev.
3       | Chapter 1
4       | Chapter 1
```

What I wanted to achieve is to limit Chapter Number data return from each Book Chapters only to 2 rows.

Example of data that I want

```
Book Id | Book Name | Chapter_Number
1  | Java Programming | Chapter 1
1  | Java Programming | Chapter 1v2
2  | Java Programming | Chapter 2 Release 1
2  | Java Programming | Chapter 2 Rev.
3  | Java Programming | Chapter 1
4  | Java Programming | Chapter 1
```

Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to introduce a `rank` column.   You can do this with `mysql` by using `user-defined variables`:

```
select *
from (
  select b.id, 
         b.book_name, 
         c.chapter_number,
         @rnk:=IF(@prevbookid=b.id,@rnk+1,1) rnk,
         @prevbookid:=b.id
  from books b
    join chapters c on b.id = c.bookid
    join (select @rnk:= 0, @prevbookid:= 0) t
  order by b.id, c.chapter_number
  ) t
where rnk <= 2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cef09/4)

Comment: Great idea to use user-defined variables.  Clever answer.

Comment: Perfect for my need. Thank you :)

Comment: @drgbox -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you could do this using just SQL.  You could do it in SQL with the help of some code like this:

First, get a list of chapter ids:

```
select distinct id from Chapter;
```

Then you'd have to iterate (in code) over each id, running a query such as this:

```
select * from Chapter join Book on Book.id = Chapter.Book_id where Chapter.Book_id=(the iterated id) limit 2;
```

Obviously this isn't very scalable because you have to run a query for each id in the list.  It's a good question.  I'll vote it up. Maybe someone can provide an SQL-only answer.